# UIImageView not displaying image in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am loading image from url coming from xml image not showing image

```
  CGRect mywebframe=CGRectMake(0,60,700,300);

  UIImageView*imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:mywebframe];
  NSString*imageurl=aBook.image;

  imageurl=[imageurl stringByReplacingOccurenceOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
  imageurl=[imageurl stringByTrimmingCharacterInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
  NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:imageurl];
  NSData*data=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
  UIImage*imagetemp=[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
  imageView.image=imagetemp;
  [subView addSubView:imageView];
```

Comment: Check the URL by opening it in browser, also if the image size is large it will take more time to load depends on your network connectivity speed.

Comment: What does `[FileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: url]` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet your image (`imagetemp`) is `nil`.

Too many possibilities why it is nil. Try to log every variable before you use it and you'll find the bug quickly.

Comment: its not null it is giving path of the image

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can use NSLog() to make sure your URL is correct.

Secondly, you really can not get the image that simple. I recommend a ImageView named [EGOImageView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading) You only need to give a place holding image and a URL, you can have the an asynchronized imageView.It also cache images for you automatically.